# Kth Smallest SUM In Two Sorted Arrays - Binary Search Solution

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I am trying to solve an interview practice problem.

The problem is:

> Given two integer arrays sorted in ascending order and an integer k. Define sum = a + b, where a is an element from the first array and b is an element from the second one. Find the kth smallest sum out of all possible sums.
>
> For example
>
> Given [1, 7, 11] and [2, 4, 6].
>
> For k = 3, return 7.
>
> For k = 4, return 9.
>
> For k = 8, return 15.

We define n as the size of A, and m as the size of B.
I know how to solve it using heap (O(k log min(n, m, k)) time complexity).  But the problem states that there is another binary search method to do it with O( (m + n) log maxValue), where maxValue is the max number in A and B. Can anyone give some comments for solving it using **binary search**?

My thinking is that we may use x = A[] + B[] as the searching object, because the k-th x is what we want. If so, how can x be updated in binary search? How can I check if the updated x is valid or not (such a pair really exists or not)?

Thank you

The original problem is here:
https://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/kth-smallest-sum-in-two-sorted-arrays/

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212037/find-the-pair-across-2-arrays-with-kth-largest-sum

Comment: @Adrian Thanks. I saw that before, but it is a heap solution. I would like to see a binary search solution.

Comment: Unique k-th sum values or non-unique ones? E.g `{{1,2},{1,2}` 3rd sum results in 3 (with the seq 2,3,3) or 4 (with 2, 3, discarded-3-duplicate, 4)?

Comment: Unique k-th sum. Discard duplicate sums

Answer (score 1):

You can solve for binary search and sliding window, and the time complexity is `O((N + M) log maxvalue)`. 

Let's think solving this problem (I call it **counting problem**).

> You are given integers N, M, S, sequences a and b. 
>   The length of sequence a is exactly N. 
>   The length of sequence b is exactly M. 
>   The sequence a, b is sorted. 
>   Please calculate the number of pairs that satisfies `a[i]+b[j]<=S (0<=i<=N-1, 0<=j<=M-1)`.

Actually, this **counting problem** can solve for **binary search** in `O(N log M)` time. 
Surprisingly, this problem can solve for `O(N+M)`.

**Binary Search Algorithm** 
You can solve the maximum value of x that satisfies `a[i] + b[x] <= S --> b[x] <= S - a[i]` for `O(log M)`. 
Therefore, you can solve the number of value of x for `O(log M)` because it is equal to x+1.

**O(N+M) Algorithm** 
Actually, if you do `i++`, the value of x is equal or less than previous value of x. 
So you can use sliding window algorithm and. 
You can solve for O(N+M), because you have to do operation `i++` N times, and operation `x--` M times.

**Solving this main problem** 
You can binary_search for S and you can solve the inequality `(counting problem's answer <= K)`. 
The answer is the maximum value of S. 
The time complexity is `O((N + M) log maxvalue)`.

Comment: K th smallest sum , not the sum value is K.

Comment: OK. This sentense was little confusing, so I edited.

Comment: @square1001 Thank you for spending so many efforts in answering my question. I think here S is not known beforehand. The purpose is to find the k-th smallest pair (without duplicates) {A[], B[]}.

Comment: @JohnTan Take your time to understand what he's proposing and you'll discover he has a point. In essence, it is searching for the minimal sum which has k-1 other sums below it. So, assume an objective function (`obj_fun`) of "For a given value S of the sum, count how many other sums lesser then S" (his *counting problem*) - which you can solve  in n*log(m) or m*log(n) time. Then binary search using `obj_fun` in the usual way, (`min=a1+b1`, `max=a(n)+b(n)`, take `mid=(min+max)/2`, evaluate `obj_fun(mid)`, if lower than `k-1` make `max=mid-1`, if higher make `min=mid+1`, etc)